# Audacity hangs when using audio drivers other than JACK

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, audacity

I have the latest Audacity version (2.1.1), yet it doesn't matter what version I use, because I've had the same problem since I first installed it months ago.

Audacity has major issues when I use any driver other than JACK - it works flawlessly under JACK, but other sounds are completely disabled until I turn off the JACK driver. I would rather use ALSA or PulseAudio, but during playback of audio, the sounds become static, and when I click the stop button, the entire program hangs.

This may be due to seeking by clicking on the bar above the editing area during playback. Is there any way to resolve the situation?

**NOTE:** I just tried to reproduce the problem and have failed, however I did get some terminal output which may be related to the problem:

```
(process:27314): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised

(process:27314): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised

(process:27314): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised

(process:27314): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)

... (last message repeated 3 times)

Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
Expression 'ret' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1736
Expression 'AlsaOpen( &alsaApi->baseHostApiRep, params, streamDir, &self->pcm )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1904
Expression 'PaAlsaStreamComponent_Initialize( &self->capture, alsaApi, inParams, StreamDirection_In, NULL != callback )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2171
Expression 'PaAlsaStream_Initialize( stream, alsaHostApi, inputParameters, outputParameters, sampleRate, framesPerBuffer, callback, streamFlags, userData )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2840
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:618:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave

... (last message repeated a bunch of times)

Expression 'ret' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1736
Expression 'AlsaOpen( &alsaApi->baseHostApiRep, params, streamDir, &self->pcm )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1904
Expression 'PaAlsaStreamComponent_Initialize( &self->capture, alsaApi, inParams, StreamDirection_In, NULL != callback )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2171
Expression 'PaAlsaStream_Initialize( stream, alsaHostApi, inputParameters, outputParameters, sampleRate, framesPerBuffer, callback, streamFlags, userData )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2840
Expression 'stream->playback.pcm' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 4611
Expression 'stream->playback.pcm' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 4611
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred

... (last message repeated 4 times)
```

The errors about JACK is not important, since it uses JACK by default, and I didn't have it running this time around.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be [a known issue](http://bugzilla.audacityteam.org/show_bug.cgi?id=276). Two things to note:

- Specifying a high latency on launch [seems to help](http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=81315):

  ```
  env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=300 audacity
  ```
- There are things happening in the development version (September 2015) that probably aren't in Ubuntu's repo version yet, that are helping to fix this.

So I'd try the first then try updating to the development version... And failing that, engaing with the developer directly under [that bug report](http://bugzilla.audacityteam.org/show_bug.cgi?id=276).

Comment: Tried your command. I'm still getting errors. [Pastebin here.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14416976/)